# How many Headgear and Outfits are available?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, super-smash-bros-4

I've been trying to get my last achievement for Smash 3ds, which involves getting all Headgear, Custom Moves, and Outfits. I've already gotten all of the moves (save for Mewtwo), but I have no idea how much further I have to go to get all of the Headgear / Outfits.

Additionally, what are some good ways to earn these? All I really do is play a smash run every day because I find that the most fun, but I'm open to a method that gets them faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[List of Mii Headgear and Outfits](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Character_customization)

There are also a few that are unlockable by completing certain challenges, but you should have those already if this is your last challenge.

As for the best way to unlock them, that's mostly up to you. It's very random. Smash Run is a good option, and you're doing that already. Classic Mode is the other main option. Playing as a Mii Fighter will make you a bit more likely to receive Mii items.

Comment: Supposing that I play as swordfighter / brawler / gunner, am I more likely to get outfits for that as well? Thanks, also! I guess I'll start doing smash runs as a mii instead.

Comment: I'm not sure if the specific Mii Fighter type matters. I wish the game weren't so cryptic on how you can get this stuff.

Comment: Agreed. I also wish they had better ways to track your progress on _anything_. I inevitably had to check every character to see if I had all their moves, and if not, play them. Start at top left, finish in bottom right. Super frustrating.

Comment: Ironically, I only had one to go, and I got it my first round as a mii.

Answer (score -1):

Here's all the [hats](http://smashbros-miiverse.com/unlockables/hats) and [outfits](http://smashbros-miiverse.com/unlockables/outfits) and how to unlock them. While some of them are achievement unlocked, this should tell you witch one your missing and if it is randomly unlocked.

Comment: Hi Dodo,while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.